# PHP Image upload to server, and save path to the PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, database, file, postgresql, upload

I'd like to modify my form to upload files to the server, with the full path of the uploaded file saved to the database.

**Code:**

```
//EDYCJA AGENTA

    function edycja_agenta($id)

    {

         $q = "SELECT id, ostatnie_logowanie, profil_id, adres_ip, status, lokalizacja, adres_mac, wersja_programu FROM agenty WHERE id=$id";

        $wynik =  pg_query($q) or die("Zapytanie niepoprawne:".$q);

        $ilosc=pg_numrows($wynik);



         $i=0;

while ($i < $ilosc) {

        $id=pg_result($wynik,$i,"id");

        $lokalizacja=pg_result($wynik,$i,"lokalizacja");

        $ostatnie_logowanie=pg_result($wynik,$i,"ostatnie_logowanie");

        $profil_id=pg_result($wynik,$i,"profil_id");

        $adres_ip=pg_result($wynik,$i,"adres_ip");

        $status=pg_result($wynik,$i,"status");

        $adres_mac=pg_result($wynik,$i,"adres_mac");

        $wersja_programu=pg_result($wynik,$i,"wersja_programu");  

        $i++;

  }

    echo'



<form  action="agent.php?id='.$id.'&zapisz" method="post" name="formularz">







    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Lokalizacja</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="lokalizacja" required value="'.$lokalizacja.'" />
      <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
  </div>



    <label class="control-label" >Profil</label>

    <div class="controls">

            <select class="formularz_select" name="profil_nazwa" id="lista">';

            echo pobierz_profile($profil_id);

            echo ' </select>

    </div>







 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zapisz dane</button>









</form>



';

    }



//KONIEC EDYCJA AGENTA





  //ZAPIS EDYCJA AGENTA

    function zapisz($id)

    {





         if (isset($_POST['profil_nazwa']) ) 

        $profil_nazwa= $_POST['profil_nazwa'];

        if (isset($_POST['lokalizacja']) ) 

        $lokalizacja= $_POST['lokalizacja'];





if( isset($_POST['lokalizacja'])  AND isset($_POST['profil_nazwa'])) {  

         $zapytanie      =  "SELECT id FROM profile WHERE nazwa='$profil_nazwa'";

         $odpowiedz     =  pg_query($zapytanie) or die("Zapytanie niepoprawne:".$zapytanie);

         $id_profilu    =  pg_result($odpowiedz,0,"id");





            $q = "UPDATE agenty SET profil_id='$id_profilu', lokalizacja='$lokalizacja', status='1'  WHERE id=$id";

            $wynik =  pg_query($q) or die("Zapytanie niepoprawne 1:".$q);

           if($wynik) {  $GLOBALS[komunikat_edycja_agenta]="<div id=\"myAlert\" class=\"alert alert-success fade\"><a class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\">×</a>Edycja zakończona sukcesem</div>";

           } else {       $GLOBALS[komunikat_edycja_agenta]="<div id=\"myAlert\" class=\"alert alert-error fade\"><a class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\">×</a>Edycja zakończona błędem</div>";     

    }





}



  }



//KONIEC ZAPISU EDYCJA AGENTA
```

I know that I need to use an input type file, but I have no clue on how to save the path to the database and how to specify the folder for the uploaded file.

Comment: Start out with adding an enctype attribute to your form tag: enctype='multipart/form-data'

Comment: and how shall i specify the path for file to be saved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there have some keys for upload file:

1. `<input type='file' name='file_name' />` must have this kind of input;
2. `<form encrypt='multipart/form-data'>` form must have encrypt property
3. get uploaded file you need use $_FILES in php server side,in this case,you could 
   print $_FILES['file_name'] to see details,remember $_FILES array key must eq to input's    name value("file_name")
4. to store file you need use move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$save_path),$save_path must writable

to see an example,please go to here:http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp